# How to select first 5 records and group rest others records in sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

Suppose I have 2 columns NAME and COUNT.

| NAME | COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| a1 | 2 |
| a2 | 4 |
| a3 | 5 |
| a4 | 1 |
| a5 | 6 |
| a6 | 2 |
| a7 | 4 |
| a8 | 6 |
| a9 | 7 |
| a10 | 4 |
| a11 | 1 |

I want to select first 5 records and group the rest others as one record( naming that record as others)

The output I need is

| NAME | COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| a1 | 2 |
| a2 | 4 |
| a3 | 5 |
| a4 | 1 |
| a5 | 6 |
| others | 24 |

In others I need sum of all the count values excluding first 5 records.

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: _First_ - as in alphabetical order?

Comment: RDBMS: postgreSQL

Comment: By first I mean the first 5 rows we get in any order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use a union approach with the help of `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NAME) rn
    FROM yourTable t
)

SELECT NAME, COUNT
FROM
(
    SELECT NAME, COUNT, 1 AS pos FROM cte WHERE rn <= 5
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'others', SUM(COUNT), 2 FROM cte WHERE rn > 5
) t
ORDER BY pos, NAME;
```

Comment: Upvoted. (But I wouldn't reuse t as table alias - for clarity.)